# authenticate to aws with axios and aws4

Tags: amazon-web-services, axios, amazon-polly

I'm trying to get authenticated to AWS to send request to AWS Polly, from a javascript code in a WordPress editor.  I've followed several examples on internet, but I always get errors.

```
const CREDS = {
      accessKeyId: "xxx",
      secretAccessKey: "xxx"
      // region: "eu-west-1"
    }; 

  axios(
      aws4.sign(
        {
          host: "polly.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
          method: "GET",
          url:
            "https://polly.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/voices?Engine=neural&IncludeAdditionalLanguageCodes=no&LanguageCode=en-US",
          data: {},
          body: {},
          path:
            "/v1/voices?Engine=neural&IncludeAdditionalLanguageCodes=no&LanguageCode=en-US"
        },
        CREDS
      )
    ).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      // ...
    });
```

> > xhr.js:126 Refused to set unsafe header "Host" setRequestHeader @ xhr.js:126 forEach @ utils.js:238 dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:120
> >     xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:12 dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:52
> >     Promise.then (async) request @ Axios.js:61 wrap @ bind.js:9
> >     (anonymous) @ edit.js:88 Vh @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:163 Uh @
> >     react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:14 Xh @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:14 af
> >     @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:14 Yh @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:164
> >     nd @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:15 nc @
> >     react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:15 Of @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:38 Ac
> >     @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:39 unstable_runWithPriority @
> >     react.min.js?ver=16.9.0:26 Ma @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:52 Be @
> >     react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:119 xi @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:39
> >     xhr.js:126 Refused to set unsafe header "Content-Length"
> >     setRequestHeader @ xhr.js:126 forEach @ utils.js:238
> >     dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:120 xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:12 dispatchRequest
> >     @ dispatchRequest.js:52 Promise.then (async) request @ Axios.js:61
> >     wrap @ bind.js:9 (anonymous) @ edit.js:88 Vh @
> >     react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:163 Uh @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:14 Xh
> >     @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:14 af @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:14
> >     Yh @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:164 nd @
> >     react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:15 nc @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:15 Of
> >     @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:38 Ac @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:39
> >     unstable_runWithPriority @ react.min.js?ver=16.9.0:26 Ma @
> >     react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:52 Be @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:119 xi
> >     @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:39 xhr.js:178 GET
> >     https://polly.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/voices?Engine=neural&IncludeAdditionalLanguageCodes=no&LanguageCode=en-US
> >     403 (Forbidden)

and with this one

```
      aws4.sign(
        {
          service: "polly",
          region: "eu-west-1",
          method: "GET",
          path:
            "/v1/voices?Engine=neural&IncludeAdditionalLanguageCodes=no&LanguageCode=en-US",
          headers: {},
          body: "{}"
        },
        CREDS
      )
    ).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      // ...
    });
```

> isURLSameOrigin.js:57 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'protocol' of undefined
>       at isURLSameOrigin (isURLSameOrigin.js:57)
>       at dispatchXhrRequest (xhr.js:109)
>       at new Promise ()
>       at xhrAdapter (xhr.js:12)
>       at dispatchRequest (dispatchRequest.js:52)

I don't understand why is so complicatd. Why am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the first issue, you shouldn't provide the host header. In the second issue, it looks like you are failing to provide the URL to Axios.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Now  I get the same error for both (xhr.js:126 Refused to set unsafe header "Host", xhr.js:126 Refused to set unsafe header "Content-Length")

Comment: If I were in your shoes, I would remove aws4, polly, and in fact AWS, completely from the picture. Can you use axios to invoke GET against an HTTPS URL against a basic endpoint like http://dummy.restapiexample.com/.

Comment: @jarmod What do you mean by a basic endpoint?  I need to invoke AWS Polly service through a htpp request, and I cannot get it with aws4 (and AWS-SDK doesn't allow authentication in a browser). What do you suggest>

Comment: I gave you an endpoint. I could be wrong, but you appear to be struggling initially with using axios correctly, hence my suggestion to remove the complexities of AWS Polly and signing, and simply ensure that you can successfully use axios.

Comment: @jarmod NO, I don't have any problem with axios. I've tried the endpoint you say and it works ok. The problem is with signing the request to AWS with aws4.

Comment: I've made some progress. The last slash in the path wasn't necessary. I now manage to connect via GET to describe voices but when I send a POST to synthesis voices a get a 403

Answer (score 11):

AWS4 was causing me a headache for days! I found a solution using amplify instead. Its create the correct headers

```js
import {Signer} from '@aws-amplify/core';

let request = {         
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://polly.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/voices?Engine=neural&IncludeAdditionalLanguageCodes=no&LanguageCode=en-US',
        data: '' 
    } 
    let access_info = {
        access_key: xxxxx, 
        secret_key: xxxxxx,
        session_token: xxxxx
    }
    let service_info = {
        service: 'polly',
        region: 'eu-west-1'
    }


    //use amplify sign()function to create the signed headers;
    let signedRequest =  Signer.sign(request,access_info,service_info)

    //remove host from header
    delete signedRequest.headers['host']

    //I normally create an instance if I need to intercept my response or request
    var instance = axios.create();


    let response = await instance(signedRequest).then(function (response) {    
       console.log(response);
       return response

     }).catch(function (error) {

         //... handle errors

     });
```

I hope this can help you

Answer (score 2):

Jim-miraidev thanks so much for this!

I made it into an axios interceptor [here](https://gist.github.com/ziggy6792/a3d177b8926a1ed679c71a9703413df8)

Which can be used like this

```
const interceptor = aws4Interceptor(
  {
    region: "eu-west-2",
    service: "execute-api",
  },
  {
    accessKeyId: "",
    secretAccessKey: "",
  }
);
```

Inspired by [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws4-axios) package which I was previously (incorrectly) using in the browser.

Comment: Glad to help, and a good solution using the interceptor

Comment: Could you please clarify why https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws4-axios can't be used in the browser?